# Could not find 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.9.1'

Tags: android

**My build.gradle(:app) code**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tk.yurkiv.recipes"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
     }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
    
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.vlonjatg.android:progress-activity:1.1.1'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.0.2'
    compile('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.9.1'
    compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.leonardoxh:fake-search-view:0.3.1'
}
```

**Build Output**

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.9.1.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/E:/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.9.1/material-dialogs-0.7.9.1.pom
      file:/E:/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.9.1/material-dialogs-0.7.9.1.jar
      file:/E:/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.9.1/material-dialogs-0.7.9.1.pom
      file:/E:/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.9.1/material-dialogs-0.7.9.1.jar
      file:/E:/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.9.1/material-dialogs-0.7.9.1.pom
      file:/E:/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.9.1/material-dialogs-0.7.9.1.jar
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.9.1/material-dialogs-0.7.9.1.pom
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.9.1/material-dialogs-0.7.9.1.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.9.1/material-dialogs-0.7.9.1.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.9.1/material-dialogs-0.7.9.1.jar
      https://jitpack.io/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.9.1/material-dialogs-0.7.9.1.pom
      https://jitpack.io/com/afollestad/material-dialogs/0.7.9.1/material-dialogs-0.7.9.1.jar
  Required by:
      project :app
```

Comment: sometimes it is resolved by cleaning and invalidating cache .try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this issue on the library repository

https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs/issues/990

The library is moved to JCenter so in your build.gradle make sure you have this line jcenter()

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        ...
    }
}
```

In any new project, this code is added by default

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.9.1'
```

with this:

```
implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:3.3.0'
```

Looks like you are running a legacy project which needs a lot of refactoring.

**NOTE**: This solution might work for the specific question but not for the project. Update your project to fix every other issues.

**Edit**: Also see **AmrDeveloper**'s answer below assuming the project is old.